# Play next youtube video automatic

Tags: video, youtube, autoplay, autoplay-media-studio

[i want to play all video automatic when user click on autoplay button and all video of recycleview play one by one
In same activity    ]

1.i like to play video like sub 4 sub app user click on autoplay videos all videos Play after 1 video finished it add coin in wallet then second video play again it add coins in wallet
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rdv2g.jpg)

```
public void loadYTVideo() {
    String tag_json_obj = "json_login_req";

    String GET_POST_LIST = BaseUrl.ADMIN_URL + BaseUrl.YT_API;
    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, GET_POST_LIST,
            new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {

                    Log.i("tagconvertstr", "[" + response + "]");
                    if (!response.equalsIgnoreCase("failure")) {
                        try {

                            JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(response);
                            JSONArray array = obj.getJSONArray("response");

                            // JSONArray array = new JSONArray("response");

                            for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {

                                JSONObject rlist = array.getJSONObject(i);


                                Log.i("rlist", "[" + rlist + "]");

                                yt_videos.add(new ytVideo(
                                        rlist.getString("id"),
                                        rlist.getString("video_title"),
                                        rlist.getString("video_id"),
                                        rlist.getString("play_time"),
                                        rlist.getString("video_reward")


                                ));
                            }

                            //creating adapter object and setting it to recyclerview
                            ytAdapter = new ytAdapter(activity, yt_videos);
                            recyclerView.setAdapter(ytAdapter);
                            dialog.dismiss();
                            setDataAdapter2();

                            RelativeLayout layout_no_result = findViewById(R.id.layout_no_result);
                            layout_no_result.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();

                            dialog.dismiss();
                            RelativeLayout layout_no_result = findViewById(R.id.layout_no_result);
                            layout_no_result.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);


                        }
                    }
                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                }
            }) {

        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();

            params.put("user_id", AppController.getInstance().getId());
            Log.d("parmas", "getParams: " + params);

            return params;
        }

    };

    stringRequest.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(5000,
            DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES,
            DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));

    AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(stringRequest);

}

private void setDataAdapter2() {

    if (yt_videos.size() > 0) {

        ytAdapter = new ytAdapter(activity, yt_videos);
        recyclerView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(ytAdapter);
    } else {
        recyclerView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        Toast.makeText(activity, "Oops! Nothing found.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}


public void SetCounText() {
    //data int


}

public void setPointsText() {
    points_textView.setText("0");
    user_main_points(points_textView);
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    AppController.getInstance();
    user_main_points(points_textView);
    super.onResume();
}

public void showProgressDialog() {
    if (alertDialog != null && !alertDialog.isShowing()) {
        alertDialog.show();
    }
}

public void hideProgressDialog() {
    if (alertDialog != null && alertDialog.isShowing()) {
        alertDialog.dismiss();
    }
}


private void loadYoutubeVideo() {
    youTubePlayerView.getYouTubePlayerWhenReady(new YouTubePlayerCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onYouTubePlayer(@NonNull YouTubePlayer youTubePlayer) {
            youTubePlayer.loadVideo(videoId, 0);
        }
    });
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    dialog.dismiss();

    // Video Ads
    String typeOfAds = adsSettings_controller.getQuizPageAds();
    switch (typeOfAds) {
        case "Admob":
            Constant.showRewardedAdmobAds((Activity) activity);
            break;
        case "Facebook":
            Constant.showRewardedFacebookAds((Activity) activity);
            break;
        case "Vungle":
            Constant.showRewardedVungleAds((Activity) activity);
            break;

        case "UnityAds":
            //Unity
            UnityAdsDisplayRewardedAd();

            break;

        case "AdColony":
            Constant.ShowAdcolonyAds((Activity) activity);

            break;

        case "Startapp":
            Constant.StartappRewardedVideo((Activity) activity);

            break;

        case "applovin":
            Constant.ApplovinShowAds((Activity) activity);

            break;
    }


    super.onBackPressed();
}


//unity
@Override
public void
```

onInitializationComplete() {
//   UnityAdsDisplayRewardedAd();

```
}

@Override
public void onInitializationFailed(UnityAds.UnityAdsInitializationError error, String message) {
    Log.e("UnityAdsExample", "Unity Ads initialization failed with error: [" + error + "] " + message);
}

public void UnityAdsDisplayRewardedAd() {
    UnityAds.load(getString(R.string.unity_adUnitId), loadListener);
    UnityAds.show(activity, getString(R.string.unity_adUnitId));
}
//unity end
```

}

1. Please give me solution of this``